# Searching for an item over a non-uniform query distribution

Tags: data-structures, search-algorithms, search-trees

If I have a static set of $n$ items in a database that are all queried with uniform probability it makes sense to put them in a binary search tree. This way any given search will take, on average, $O(\ln n)$.

What happens now, if the items are not queried uniformly? As a silly example, say that one item is queried 1000 more frequently than any other item. Would it make sense check for that item first and independently, before looking in a search tree of the other items (the so-called [LenPEG](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/lenpeg.html) method)?

For concreteness, let's say the items are queried with a likelyhood that is static, and drawn from a Poisson distribution. What would be the optimal way to structure the data so that the average search time is minimized?

Comment: Hint: Huffman trees. (And as an aside: Splay trees.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Optimal Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree) is exactly what you need.

Welcome to the site!